# Is PDF versioning available in Adobe Acrobat DC?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, pdf-reader, adobe-reader-dc

Is versioning available for adobe acrobat DC? I'm new to editing PDFs and to Adobe Acrobat DC, but I've been reading contradictory things on line.

Is versioning possible? If so, how do I enable it?

**Edit**: I'm asking because there is a desire to track updates/versions and possibly go back to a prior version of a PDF.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you're asking? This sounds as if it is an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem where explaining the reason you ask would result in a restatement of the true issue followed by a much more satisfactory answer. Also include links to what you read online. Please click [edit] and add them to your original question along with the background asked for. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please click [edit].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, after you have saved a PDF and close it, you cannot roll back to or view prior versions of the PDF.